# Enque script based on url paramater

Tags: wp-admin, actions, wp-enqueue-script

I'm using the following to enqueue a script in admin.

```
function add_admin_scripts( $hook ) {

    global $post;

    if ( $hook == 'post-new.php' || $hook == 'post.php' ) {
        if ( 'custom' === $post->post_type ) {     
            wp_enqueue_script(  'myscript', get_stylesheet_directory_uri().'/js/custom.js' );
        }
    }
}
add_action( 'admin_enqueue_scripts', 'add_admin_scripts', 10, 1 );
```

But I want to enqueue when `action=edit` is in the URL parameter.

> http://mysite/wp-themes/my-theme/wp-admin/post.php?post=185&action=edit

Is this possible?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

There are a couple of ways to do this. The easiest way is to use `$_GET`:

```
if ( ( $hook == 'post-new.php' || $hook == 'post.php' ) && $_GET['action'] == 'edit' ) {
    // Enqueue your scripts here
}
```

You can also use the [`get_current_screen();`](https://codex.wordpress.org/Function_Reference/get_current_screen) function instead of using a global variable.

Comment: Thanks! I tried get_current_screen() but it does not store the action parameter

Comment: You're welcome. I was talking about the URL base, as I mentioned _"instead of global"_.